# xpath expression in findnodes() returning empty nodelist

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, xlib

XML:

```
<zoo xmlns="http://www.zoo.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:schemaLocation="http://www.zoo.com employee.xsd">

<area id="1" posizione="nord" nome="scimmie">
    <animale>
        <nome>Gigi</nome>
        <sesso>Male</sesso>
        <eta>3</eta>
    </animale>

    <animale>
        <nome>Gigia</nome>
        <sesso>Female</sesso>
        <eta>2</eta>
    </animale>
</area>

<area id="2" posizione="nord" nome="giraffe">
    <animale>
        <nome>Giro</nome>
        <sesso>Male</sesso>
        <eta>6</eta>
    </animale>

    <animale>
        <nome>Gira</nome>
        <sesso>Female</sesso>
        <eta>5</eta>
    </animale>
</area>
</zoo>
```

code:

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $doc = $parser->parse_file("../xml/animals.xml");
my $root = $doc->getDocumentElement();

my $new_animal = $doc->createElement("animale");

my $name_element = $doc->createElement("nome");
$name_element->appendTextNode($name);

my $gender_element = $doc->createElement("sesso");
$gender_element->appendTextNode($gender);

my $age_element = $doc->createElement("eta");
$age_element->appendTextNode($age);

$new_animal->appendChild($name_element);
$new_animal->appendChild($gender_element);
$new_animal->appendChild($age_element);

my $area_element = $root -> findnodes("//area[\@id=$area]")->get_node(1);

$area_element->appendChild($new_animal);
```

$area is the id of an area (usually 1 now that I'm testing)

my purpose is to create a new animal and to add it to the proper area

but I have the problem that the istruction

```
    my $area_element = $root -> findnodes("//area[\@id=$area]")->get_node(1);
```

won't work, because $area_element is undef, because findnodes always returns an empty nodelist (checked printing the size()).

I think that the problem is the xpath expression inside findnodes, but I can't understand what's wrong, I use the same expression with another library (XML::XPath) and it's working.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URI for the deafult namespace in your XML is `http://www.zoo.com`, so you must specify this in your XPath expressions for the nodes to be picked up.

The way to do this is to declare a `XML::LibXML::XPathContext` object that assigns a name to this namespace. The name can then be used in XPath expressions to access the nodes.

If you write

```
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new;
$xpc->registerNs('zoo', 'http://www.zoo.com');
```

you now have a context in which the XML's default namespace is named `zoo`. Now you can write

```
my $area_element = $xpc->findnodes("//zoo:area[\@id=$area]", $doc)->get_node(1);
```

and you will find the correct `<area>` element.

Comment: I tried with your code, but I get this: ----------
Software error:
XPathContext: lost current node at /Users/toyo/Sites/zoo/cgi-bin/_nuovo_animale.cgi line 76 ---------

line 76 is:        
my $area_element = $xpc -> findnodes("//zoo:area[\@id=$area]")->get_node(1);

Comment: @qwertoyo, This is a new problem, and there's really no space to discuss it here. Please ask a new question, and provide the minimum runnable code required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @qwertoyo, Try the simpler: `my ($area_element) = $xpc->findnodes("//zoo:area[\@id=$area]", $doc);`

Comment: saw your edit on the answer (added the ", $doc"), now it seems to work, i'm testing it

Answer (score -2):

The namespace declaration is wrong, it should say `<zoo xmlns:zoo="http://www.zoo.com"` or the like.

Comment: `xmlns="http://www.zoo.com"` without a namespace ID merely binds the *default* namespace, i.e. the namespace for all elements that don't carry a prefix. If there is no definition of a default namespace then it is as if a declaration `xmlns=""` had been used.

Comment: `<foo xmlns="...">` and `<bar:foo xmlns:bar="...">` are correct and equivalent (assuming the children mimic the lack/presence of the prefix). The namespace defined in `<foo xmlns:bar="...">` is never used, so your advice is incorrect.

Comment: Wrong answer. There is nothing wrong with the namespace declaration. Downvoting.